# Is calling componentDidMount within a function bad practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in my ReactJS app that sends an axios POST request to the server to delete a certain element from my database.

Basically, I have a list and I can delete certain items from it, however, React only displays the changes made by deleting an element after refreshing the page.

Here is the delete function that I use:

```
handleDelete (event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    axios.get('todos/delete?id='+id)
        .then(function(response) {
        });
    this.componentDidMount();
}
```

`componentDidMount()` fetches data from my database and stores it in the state.
I found that, if I call `componentDidMount` within the function, that it displays the changes right away, however, I kind of feel like that's a rather unprofessional way of doing what I'm trying to achieve.
Therefore my questions are:

- Is it considered bad practice to call a lifecycle method within another function?
- Is there a better way to get the page to display the changes right away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you shouldn't really do that.

**[componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)** is just a lifecycle method of your component. What you want is this structure:

```
fetchData () { ... };

handleDelete (event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    axios.get('todos/delete?id='+id)
        .then(function(response) {
        });
    this.fetchData();
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}
```

This is a simplified example but you get the point.

**NOTE:** in the **handleDelete** function if you want the **fetchData** call to happen **after** the axios call your should but the code inside the **then**

```
axios.get('todos/delete?id='+id)
     .then(() => {
       this.fetchData();
     });
```

Comment: Note that you should place the `this.fetchData()` inside the `handleDelete` inside the `.then` block so that it won't re-fetch the data before actually deleting it.

Comment: @Mico I know but I just copied what he had. I'll add a note though

Comment: yes sorry, maybe I should have commented on the original post but whatever.

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly! I just had to declare `var _this = this` and then `_this.fetchData()` because otherwise it gave me an error

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**- No it is recommended to call lifecycle method in any function.

**Answer 2**- better recommednded way , call all server function in `ComponentDidMount`

for More refrence [check here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html)

You can do your operation in this way :-

```
  componentDidMount(){
     // do some get opration to get data from server
      getFunction();
    }
   handleDelete (event) {
        var id = event.target.id;
        axios.get('todos/delete?id='+id)
            .then(function(response) {
                // get operation here in response
            });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's a bad practice. You can either use React lifecycle to update your state or directly within the `handleDelete` function.

```
handleDelete = ({ target }) => {
 const { id } = target;
 axios.get('todos/delete?id=='+id')
   .then(response => { 
       const todos = this.state.todos;
       todos.splice(indexOfTheItem,1);
       this.setState({ todos });
      })
```